# Difference between transform: translate and position:relative;?

Tags: css, css-position, css-transforms

As the title says, what are the differences between transform: translate(x, y) and position: relative.

Since they both accomplish the same thing (position elements) anyway, then how do they differ in purpose and application?

I read an article about centering elements using "transform: translate;" that said it is better to use "transform" due to GPU and optimization reason, but I don't really see the problem since it's not a big deal anyway if you're just re-positioning an element and not animating it.

So in the end, how are they both different and in what ways?

Comment: Is something has position:absolute, you can use transform on it still but you can't use position relative on that same element.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was referring to the re-positioning difference between "transform: translate;" and "position:absolute;", I apologize if I had not made myself clear.

Comment: Also [**CSS-Tricks Article**](http://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/) which includes link to [**Paul Irish Article**](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

Comment: I've already read that article and as I've stated in my query, it addresses animations and not re-positioning.

I would like to know how these two properties differ in their pure re-positioning abilities. 

For examples, "position:relative;" and "position:absolute;" are different in a way that "absposed" elements are taken out of the normal flow. 

These are the kind of differences I'm talking about. 

Thanks.

Comment: Then I suggest that your question has no real answer and is primarily something that is a subjective issue.

Comment: Are you suggesting that there may be no difference between them at all?

Comment: As I said, when you use them would be different. You can't use position:relative to affect an element that has position absolute...but you can with translate. so, perhaps its the usage that makes them different.

Comment: Also, see this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XJgWbo

Comment: @Paulie_D: That would be a valid answer to the question assuming it was correct. There is nothing subjective about this question.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this question "too broad" because the OP clearly states that the question is about `translate()` vs relative positioning for the very specific purpose of shifting elements from their original positions. Is that not narrowed-down enough for some of you?

Answer (score 3):

Basically `translate` relies on [CSS3 2D Transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) while the `position` property is a [CSS2 level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

In browser that support it has been said that using `translate` will boost the entire graphical peformance of the browser,

but not all browser do support it,

so if you care to give widespread browser support CSS2 position is surely better,

while `transform:translate()` is the future.

Comment: That's almost certainly not the main difference. These are two completely different things meant for completely different purposes.

Comment: these were just background information, considering just moving a 2d element , don't you think they can serve the same purpose? surely Chris Coyier's and Paul Irish's are a deeper type of researches (Paulie_D comment link above)

Comment: @BoltClock care to explain?

Comment: Come on, this answer is from 2015. Transforms are not the future, they are very much the present. Any browser not supporting it is from the past.